# If, Match and Index function returning error

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of cells containing names in A6:A12.

I also have corresponding values in columns B, C, D and E.

I want to compare the value of C3 to see if it matches in the names then extract the corresponding values in B, C, D, E and placed them in column G, H, I and J.

This is the formula I used:

```
(=IF(MATCH($C$3,$A6:$A12,0),INDEX($A6:$E12,1,1,)," N/A"))
```

But I get an error. Can someone help please?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use an `iferror`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Syntax: `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

With Vlookup you can search for a match and bring the value in another cell of the same row of the match.

On `G5`put the formula `=VLOOKUP($C$3,$A6:$E$12,2,FALSE)`

On `H5`put the formula `=VLOOKUP($C$3,$A6:$E$12,3,FALSE)`

On `I5`put the formula `=VLOOKUP($C$3,$A6:$E$12,4,FALSE)`

On `J5`put the formula `=VLOOKUP($C$3,$A6:$E$12,5,FALSE)`

Comment: Vlookup will do but it has a limit to what I wanted to achieve. The match and index was perfect for the work.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is constructed backwards.

```
G5: =INDEX($B$6:$E$12; MATCH($C$3;$A$6:$A$12; 1); 1)
H5: =INDEX($B$6:$E$12; MATCH($C$3;$A$6:$A$12; 1); 2)
' etc...
```

With error-handling:

```
G5: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$6:$E$12; MATCH($C$3;$A$6:$A$12; 1); 1); "N/A")
H5: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$6:$E$12; MATCH($C$3;$A$6:$A$12; 1); 2); "N/A")
```

Comment: The solution really worked out.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solution was the one that worked best for you, please click the checkmark next to the post to indicate that your question has been answered.